# Best way to remove drives from MDADM raid array

Tags: raid, hard-drive, mdadm

I have a situation with a RAID array; I'm concerned that the drives in the array are going to fail soon, and given their age, I would rather replace them sooner than later.

The problem I have, is that I did not set up this array.  This array is part of a business, that was set up by my predecessor, and I was given no documentation on this set up.

I've pieced together information on the set up by logging into it, such as it is configured with `mdadm`.  However, I don't know which physical drive matches which designation (slot one with `/dev/sda`).

The best idea I've come up with so far, is just stopping, and deconstructing the RAID.  I'm hoping that this will mitigate any damage, and would possibly allow me to use Clonezilla on copying the old drives to healthy drives.

I've found this guide, which I will use to deconstruct the RAID:

http://www.ducea.com/2009/03/08/mdadm-cheat-sheet/

Is there anything I'm missing here?  Is the guide complete, or are there still dangers in stopping the RAID, and removing the drives from it?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Do you have a tested and proven backup system? If not, **that** should be your task #1 before starting with drive replacements.

Comment: If you don't know what happens than stop and recreate is very bad idea. Collect all information that you can obtain. Then carefully remove only one drive with mdadm(without stop) and check /proc/mdstat

Comment: Thanks for the replies to my question.

Just to be certain Navern, I won't have any issues if I remove the wrong disk?